# Why do Football players prefer to use their family name?

Tags: surnames

I read that in Western countries, people prefer their first name over their family name, that is why they put their first name first, in form `first name + family name` For example Wayne Rooney, Steven Gerrard, ...

This is contradicts with Eastern countries, where people full name is of form `family name + first name`

But in Football (or Soccer in America), you can see in the uniform that they use their family name only. For example Rooney, Gerrard, ...

Why is that?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I don't think the question is on topic for the site, but the short answer is that the names aren't for the benefit of players, but for the spectators. One's surname is more likely to be distinctive than one's given name, although the diversity of both has been increasing sharply in recent decades. It has nothing more to do with name ordering or addressing people than do player numbers or sponsor logos.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it's not about the English language.

Comment: We definitely need a Q&A for cultures of the world, etiquette (of peoples) ... Voting as OT.

Comment: @choster I choose EL&U because of "English Usage". In the question, I show interest in English name only

Comment: Hitherto, certainly in English-speaking countries, the surname has been pre-eminent for identification. This may be changing to some extent as a lot of contacts, particularly on the telephone, only give their Christian names. It is also more common nowadays for women, even after marriage, to retain their birth surnames. Chinese will often adopt an altogether different (western-sounding) name if they are living in a western country.

Comment: There is a conflicting pull towards propriety and formality. Having 'Wayne' say on one's back could quite possibly be seen by many as being over-familiar or even childish. Addressing authority figures by their first name unbidden would almost always be seen as a sign of disrespect.

Comment: This is the way it's been done for 100 years or more.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Though one Brazillian is called *FRED*. He is Frederico Chaves Guedes. His shirt says 'FRED'.

Comment: @WS2 and [Ravel Morisson uses Ravel rather than Morisson](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-2450724/Premier-League-names-shirt-Ravel-Morrison-others.html)

Comment: What would Aloysius Shufflebotttom do?

Comment: @Edwin Play shirtless.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well Arnie Sidebottom was a footballer, who also played cricket for England. It's always refreshing to find a Snodgrass, or a Clutterbuck, among the elegant-sounding Spanish and Italian names of the top divisions.

Answer (score 2):

Because when one name is used to identify someone you do not personally know, the convention has long been to use their surname.

Hence we say:

> Shakespeare wrote *The Tempest*. Churchill was prime minister of the UK when it was at war with Hitler. Washington was the first president of the US. Einstein developed the theory of relativity. Shelley wrote *Frankenstein*.

Not:

> William wrote *The Tempest*. Winston was prime minister of the UK when it was at war with Adolf. George was the the first president of the US. Albert developed the theory of relativity. Mary wrote *Frankenstein*.

Among other things, the most common first names are probably more common than the most common surnames:

> John was the last US president to get fatally shot. John wrote "Imagine" after leaving the Beatles. John was the second US president. John was the sixth US president. John wrote *Paradise Lost*. John founded Calvinism. John wrote the *Grapes of Wrath*.

Surnames identify one in a global context more than first names do. The use by athletes is just another example of the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Because back in the days when they first invented putting names on jerseys, there would have been too many "John's" and "James's" and "Tom's" (and "Dick's" and "Harry's") to keep everyone sorted out. First names in the US have become much more creative since then, but the tradition stands.